# Referencing sections inside another file via input{}

Tags: cross-referencing

Inside my main document file, I have other documents. E.g.:

\input{File2}.

"File2" has many sections, for instance, \section{\label{Lion}Lions are great}.

I am trying to reference this section in my main document by using \ref{Lion}, but this is not working. It sends me to a wrong section.

What is the right way to do this referencing?

Thanks

Comment: \input doesn't matter, something else is wrong, but without a complete example it is not possible to say what.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer . So, to be more precise, the reference that was supposed to take the reader to section "Lion" of "File2", instead takes the reader to an equation which I labeled as follows:

\begin{equation}
y_{ijklt} = \alpha + \beta\bar{y}_{-ijklt} + \lambda'\bar{X}_{-ijklt} + \gamma' X_{ijklt} +\mu_{jt}+\delta_{kt}+\zeta_{lt} + \epsilon_{ijklt}, \label{eq1}
\end{equation}


Note: my tex files is almost 100 pages, so I can't put the whole thing here. I label the section inside "File2" as follows:

 \section{\label{Lion}Lions are great}.

Comment: And I reference that section in the main text as follows:

"A detailed explanation of how the lion behavior was recorded is deferred to Internet Appendix \ref{Lion}"

Comment: well  you will have to make a minimal example from your 100 pages. To debug code one has to see some code.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what part of the code woud you like to see? (and that I have not shown yet?)

Comment: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: start from a copy of your document and delete everything unrelated to the non working `\ref` you should be able to make a small 1 or 2 page document check the problem still occurs and add to your question.

Comment: solved the problem! so the issue was that the ref{} did not distinguish between section 2 in the main text and section 2 inside the input "File2". I changed the appendix section counts to letters instead of numbers (e.g. section A,B,C,... instead of section 1,2,3) and now it works!